# should sum and sumproduct return the same value when passed one range?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Please check out this [spreadsheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35370420/TestSumproduct2.xlsx).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5))
```

returns 10 (A26), while

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5))
```

returns 0 (A27).

Is this normal?

Thank you

Comment: please could you explain the reason for using those formulas, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes it is normal. `SUM` doesn't by default take in arrays, while `SUMPRODUCT` does if it gets them.

Comment: @CallumDS33: long story short, I am not the one using these formulas, I provide support and I reduced the issue a person was having down to this case.

Comment: @Jerry: I think it is counter-intuitive. The excel engine should be consistent. One thing that I find very scary is that the parameter types are not documented properly. For instance, in my example, passing a range in the second argument has the effect of evaluating COUNTIFS(B2:B5, <each cell in C2:C5>) and putting the result in an array. If you read the docs for countifs (https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed) it doesn't say the criteria1 can be range. Yet it can, and more adventurous users use them.

Comment: @CallumDS33: Just wanted to add that the product I provide support for uses spreadsheets created in Excel and sometimes it can have hiccups when formulas such as these ones are used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is normal.
`COUNTIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5)` normally wouldn't return an array but [`SUMPRODUCT`](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/) assumes it does and evaluates it.
`SUM` on the other hand cannot (assume).
 To make it return the same value, you need to enter it as [*array formula*](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx).
You do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Your `SUM` formula will then have `{}` braces indicating that it is being evaluated as *array formula*.

Should look like this on the formula bar if entered correctly:
`{=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5))}` and thus will return the same value as your `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: ok, this works but it doesn't make sense to me. Is there, on the microsoft site, something that describes all these intricacies? I thought you were supposed to use the curly brackets to return an array formula. SUM doesn't return an array/range. It returns only one value, hence, I should not have to change it an array formula. Excel is a hack!

Comment: If you go here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/sum-function-HP010062464.aspx, it says that the argument can be an array.

Comment: @costa Ok, I think I may have mis-explained it. See my edit. Also there's a difference between array formulas and array entered values. That's why I posted a link which discusses array formula a bit. Array Formula can return an array or a single value http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-array-formula-HP005200020.aspx